# calling enclosing functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

in the way of using enclosing functions, when I use the call method it doesn't work.

```
def foo():
    x = 20
    def bar():
        return x
    bar()
```

here when I call foo() it returns None. when I use "return bar" instead of "bar()" inside foo, it works very well with calling foo()()
so why return doesn't work in enclosing functions but print works?

Comment: Did you mean `return bar()`? Nested functions are just a scope thing, they don’t have extra control flow abilities.

Comment: @Ry- return bar itself works. but I am curious about why calling a function inside another return None. how about using print instead of return in nested function works.

Comment: Not `return bar`. `return bar()`. Or `print(bar() + 5)`. `bar` isn’t returning None, you’re just ignoring its return value.

Comment: @Ry- both works. I'm not talking about the return method. I'm asking about calling bar() inside foo doesn't return anything. try the code above.

Comment: Again, it does return something. From `bar`. Which you ignore. If you `from math import factorial` and replace `bar()` with `factorial(6)`, nothing will change. This isn’t because `factorial` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: @Ry-, why it doesn't execute bar() when it ran foo? the last line is for running bar()

Comment: `return x` returns from `bar`. It doesn’t return from `foo`. That’s not what nested functions do.

Comment: @CorvoAttano Can you say what precisely you expect to observe when you run this code, and what you observe instead? (Instead of saying "it doesn't work".)

Comment: @Ry- so it ignores last line bar()? because of no effect.

Comment: No, it runs it, which accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I suppose it returns the value of x. when I use 'print(x)' instead of 'return x' it prints value but when using return, it returns None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bar()` is an expression, `return bar()` is a statement. Except in lambda, we need return statement to return something.

Comment: this is a rational answer. so I'm interested to know where we can use expressions. modules, __main__ and ...

Comment: @CorvoAttano I can't express it very well, you can have a look at [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html), about expressions, simple statements and compound statements. I learned a lot from there.

Answer (score 0):

`foo()` doesn't return the value of `bar()`, since you didn't pass it as a return value from `foo()`.

```
def foo():
    x = 20
    def bar():
        return x
    bar()

    # No return value for foo, this equals return None
    return None

res = foo()
type(res)
# NoneType
```

If you want to propogate the return value of `bar()` via `foo()`, you need to use `return` on it:

```
def foo():
    x = 20
    def bar():
        return x

    return bar()

res = foo()
x
# 20
```